# How to reduce size of button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got some JavaScript which is making my whole page clickable through what I though was the container element. However, when I tried reducing its size, amd reducing the size of the associated widget, even the footer is clickable. Although the footer doesn't toggle according to the JavaScript code, it does toggle in as far as it reacts to the `a href "#"` and takes user to the top of the page when they are trying to select an element/link in the footer.

So how can I can I get the footer to stop being clickable? The page itself seems only to react when clicking elements on it, but almost the whole footer area is reacting to `href#`

```
<a id="mni" href="#">
<div class="container4" onclick="myFunction(this)">
     <div class="nimageone">
          <img  src="http://4309.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/IMG_20200509_165113-1-219x300.jpg" alt="" width="350" height="300" c.class="size-medium wp-image-14178" /></div>
     </div>
     <script>
         function myFunction(x){
              x.classList.toggle('change');
         }
     </script>
</div>
```

Css

```
.change 
.nimageone img {display:none}
```

[desktop here](https://4309.co.uk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not included the tree structure of your HTML element comprehensively.

You can achieve what you are trying to do with the following.

```
    <div>
   <a id="mni" href="#">
   <div class="container4" 
     onclick="myFunction(this)">
    <div class="nimageone"><img 
    src="http://4309.co.uk/wp-  
   content/uploads/2020/05/IMG_20200509_165113-1- 
  219x300.jpg" alt="" width="350" height="300" class=" 
   size-medium wp-image-14178" /></div>
  </div>


 </a> //remember to close the <a> tag here before the 
footer item

 /////Your footer item can come below here 
<footer>
</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. And where would the javascript go? As in  `<script>
         function myFunction(x){
              x.classList.toggle('change');
         }
     </script>`

Comment: That should go right before the </body> closing tag.Not inside any div

Comment: Where would the body closing and opening tags go?

Comment: Can i just write footer close open after the end of javascript with using body tags?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
     <head>

      </head>
      <body>

      //Div goes here
     //Script goes here
      </body>
     </html>

Comment: Its good practice to place your scripts  just right before closing your body tag . This might help https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_whereto.asp

Comment: It works. Great. Thanks. Not sure if it's just because i forgot to close the a tag but it worked anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to adjust the size of the button in the HTML you can set it just like you set the width and the height attributes in the 'img' tag.